# Why is the iloc function returning two diffrent answers for the below syntax?

Tags: machine-learning

I have included the snips of the code that I have written I don't understand how is dataset.iloc[:,1:-1].values and dataset.iloc[:,1].values different for the dataset where I am just using the second column.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/76XYL.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLNaL.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVTFv.png

Answer (score 0):

The -1 refers to the last column in the data frame so dataset.iloc[:1:-1] gets all the columns from the second column to the last one. The second one just gives the values for the second column.

Comment: My question is why am i getting different outputs when I use dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values I get a 2-D array whereas when I use dataset.iloc[:, 0].values I get a 1-D array

Comment: The :-1 in the columns position means you want all of the columns. The 0 means you want just the first column. The .values means to put the resulting columns in a numpy array. When more than one column gets put into a numpy array, it does it in 2-D. When only one column is converted, it does it in 1-D.